# How to see if a combination of two columns is in another table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: Transit and Connect.

```
Transit
TransitType    TransitRoute    TransitPrice
--------------------------------------------

Connect
SiteName       TransitType     TransitRoute
--------------------------------------------
```

I want to check to see if the combination of TransitType and TransitRoute in the Transit table are in the Connect table.

My current command is this:

```
    TransitRoute IN 
    (SELECT connect.TransitRoute from connect WHERE connect.SiteName = sname)
```

I also tried the following command, but got an error that said Operand should contain 1 column.

```
    SELECT * FROM transit WHERE ((transitRoute, transitType) IN (SELECT
    (connect.TransitRoute, connect.TransitType) from connect WHERE connect.SiteName = sname)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `JOIN`

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Transit AS t
JOIN Connect AS c ON t.TransitType = c.TransitType AND t.TransitRoute = c.TransitRoute
```

Since the columns you're matching have the same names, you can also abbreviate this with `USING`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Transit AS t
JOIN Connect USING (TransitType, TransitRoute)
```